# convert all video in one folder to be compatible with itunes video (OS X 10.6)

Tags: macos, video, osx-snow-leopard, itunes, conversion

I want some application (for OS X 10.6) to convert all my video files in a certain folder to MPEG in order to play them in iTunes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) or [ffmpegX](http://www.ffmpegx.com/).